# HTML and PHP Embedding

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

here am trying to fetch data from a mysql table and populate it in a html. Everything works fine But I want to echo a html button through a IF condition. I dont know if this could work..if it works...can anyone please tell me how to make it work ?. The error am getting is...INTERNAL SERVER ERROR :(

NOTE : I have commeted the exact place where i have problem

```
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
    {
    ?>  
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $rs->cnf_name ;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $rs->address;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $rs->added_on;?></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="button" class="btn" value="Edit" onClick="window.parent.editCnf('<?php echo $rs->cnf_name;?>','<?php echo $rs->username ;?>','<?php echo $rs->password;?>','<?php $rs->type;?>','<?php echo $rs->person_name;?>','<?php echo $rs->address;?>','<?php echo $rs->mobile_no?>','<?php echo $rs->email;?>','<?php echo $rs->country;?>','<?php echo $rs->city;?>','<?php echo $rs->state;?>','<?php echo $rs->area;?>')" ></td>




//PROBLEM


            <td align="center">

            <?php
            if($rs->cnf_status == 0)
            {
            echo "<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf(<?php echo $rs->user_id;?>,<?php echo $rs->cnf_status; ?>);">";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf(<?php echo $rs->user_id;?>,<?php echo $rs->cnf_status; ?>);">";

            }
?>          




            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
else
{
?>      <tr>
            <td colspan="">No data to display</td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
?>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem comes from the quotes you use with echo;
Either go for

```
echo 'htmlcode_with_doublequotes';
```

or

```
if($rs->cnf_status == 0)
{
?>
       <input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf("<?php echo $rs->user_id;?>","<?php echo $rs->cnf_status; ?>");">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
       <input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf("<?php echo $rs->user_id;?>","<?php echo $rs->cnf_status; ?>");">
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That just appears to be a problem with quotes in the echo of the button html.

```
if($rs->cnf_status == 0)
        {
        echo '<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf(<?php echo $rs->user_id;?>,<?php echo $rs->cnf_status; ?>);">';
        }
        else
        {
        echo '<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf(<?php echo $rs->user_id;?>,<?php echo $rs->cnf_status; ?>);">';

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your syntax. You have to escape " in your echos:

```
<?php
    if($rs->cnf_status == 0)
        {
        echo "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" id=\"status\" value=\"Activate\" onClick=\"window.parent.deleteCnf({$rs->user_id}, {$rs->cnf_status});\">";
        }
    else
        {
        echo "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" id=\"status\" value=\"Activate\" onClick=\"window.parent.deleteCnf({$rs->user_id}, {$rs->cnf_status});\">";
        }
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
    if($rs->cnf_status == 0)
        {
        echo '<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onclick="window.parent.deleteCnf(' . $rs->user_id . ', ' . $rs->cnf_status . ');">';
        }
    else
        {
        echo '<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onclick="window.parent.deleteCnf(' . $rs->user_id . ', ' . $rs->cnf_status . ');">';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if($rs->cnf_status == 0)
{
echo '<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf('.$rs->user_id.','.$rs->cnf_status.');">';
}
else
{
echo '<input type="button" class="btn" id="status" value="Activate" onClick="window.parent.deleteCnf('.$rs->user_id.','.$rs->cnf_status.');">';

}
?>
```